# Typo3 Search Language Variable

Tags: search, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I use Typo3 7.6.10

I have search indexed engine with results.

I have two languages but i removed the english language.

All links in the site works but in search results i have the additional variable L (example `il-progetto.html?L=0`) 
How can i remove the variable L from the link of search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a simple realurl config.
After this `progetto.html?L=0` will replaced will progetto.html

```
'preVars' => array(
    0 => array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'valueMap' => array(
            '' => 0, // German
            'en' => 1, // English
        ),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
     ),
),
```